# SQL substring replacing

Tags: sql, replace, heidisql

I am using HeidiSql  and I have a database with ~1000 URL's. Example:

```
index.php?option=com_flexicontent&view=items&cid=283&id=33
index.php?option=com_flexicontent&view=items&cid=421&id=4411
index.php?option=com_flexicontent&view=items&cid=415&id=4375
```

What I have to do is to replace the `cid=` with values from 408 to 477 to `cid=403`

I have made a SQL script like this:

```
UPDATE jos_menu
SET link = REPLACE(link, "cid=411", 'cid=403')
```

But how do I change the `cid=` values 408 to 477, without making 70 `REPLACE`s?

Comment: how many rows are updated if you execute this `...REPLACE(link, 'cid=408', 'cid=477'`?

Comment: Perhaps `CONCAT('cid=', [number])`?

Comment: at least 10. And the same for cid=409, cid=410, etc

Comment: @njk that could work, but how to pass all the numbers to it?

Comment: @Marbury It appears you are using PHP. How are you passing those numbers to the query?

Comment: @njk I am not using PHP. Just writing a SQL script and need to use this function only once.

Comment: @Marbury How are you pushing those numbers to the query?

Answer (score 1):

I cant test this but try this

```
UPDATE jos_menu
SET link = REPLACE(link, 'cid=' + SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX( 'cid=', @str) + 4, 3), 'cid=403')
WHERE Cast(SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX( 'cid=', @str) + 4, 3) as Int) > 407 And Cast(SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX( 'cid=', @str) + 4, 3) as Int) < 478
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of the table or database in phpmyadmin and save it as a .cvs file. Use excel to do the replacements. Than save it as a .cvs file again, and import it to the database back.