# SQL syntax alphanumeric characters, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I pull this ID down from my source system it looks like `9006ABCD`.

What would the syntax look like if I just want to return `9006` as the ID?

Essentially, I don't need the alpha characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL substring replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390872/sql-substring-replacing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `'9006ABCD'` is a *string* value, then you can extract the leading numbers using:

```
select left(id, patindex('%[^0-9]%', id + 'X') - 1)
```

Of course, there may be easier ways.  If you just want the first four characters, then use `left(id, 4)`.